# Connect to a RDS Database using IAM in a PHP application

Tags: php, mysql, amazon-web-services

I have developed an application using the PHP SDK for AWS. It is hosted on AWS also.

I have written a connections file, detailing all the variables and credentials required to connect to the DB, and this works fine.

However, in terms of security I was wondering if it is possible to use an IAM Role, as that is what I am using to connect to the EC2 instance, so that I am not explicitly defining the credentials?

Comment: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/UsingWithRDS.IAMDBAuth.html perhaps?

Comment: Don't depend 100% on IAM roles. Always have a username/password as a secondary measure so that a partial compromise isn't easily elevated to a full compromise.